# How to disable default keyboard navigation in Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, macos, uitableview, keyboard-shortcuts, mac-catalyst

I noticed that I can step through rows in a `UITableView` in a Mac Catalyst app by pressing the up and down arrow keys on my Mac keyboard. However, this interferes with the existing functionality in one of my view controllers. Is there a way to disable this?

I can't find any reference to this functionality in the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) documentation. The [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/mac-catalyst/) for Mac Catalyst mentions "automatic support for fundamental Mac features, such as ... keyboard navigation," so I guess this is an intentional feature, but I can't find any further reference to it or documentation for it.

I haven't seen any other examples of "automatic" keyboard navigation in my app, but ideally Apple would publish a complete list so we could know how to work with, or if needed, disable, the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution I received from Apple DTS. Just add this to the table view delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

This works in macOS 11.6 and 12.0. I don't have a 10.15 or 11.5 Mac to test with, so I'll keep my earlier `resignFirstResponder` solution, too.

Answer (score 3):

## Update as of 2021/11/06

It looks like Apple has been changing how the default focus system works and my previous solution is no longer working or required.

UIKeyCommand has a new `wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior: Bool` property which needs to be set to `true` in order for our subclasses to receive certain types of commands, including the arrow key commands.

As of at least Xcode 13.1 and macOS 11.6, maybe eariler, we can now simply add the following to a UITableViewController subclass to replace the default focus behavior with custom keyboard navigation handing:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        let upArrowCommand = UIKeyCommand(
            input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow,
            modifierFlags: [],
            action: #selector(handleUpArrowKeyPress)
        )
        upArrowCommand.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true
        
        let downArrowCommand = UIKeyCommand(
            input: UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow,
            modifierFlags: [],
            action: #selector(handleDownArrowKeyPress)
        )
        downArrowCommand.wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior = true
        
        return  [
            upArrowCommand,
            downArrowCommand
        ]
    }

    @objc
    func handleUpArrowKeyPress () {
    }

    @objc
    func handleDownArrowKeyPress () {
    }
}
```

### Previous answer (no longer working or required)

Catalyst automatically assigns UIKeyCommands for the up/down arrows to `UITableView` instances. This does not happen on iOS. You can see this in action by setting a break point in `viewDidLoad()` of a `UITableViewController` and inspecting `tableView.keyCommands`.

So I created a very simple `UITableView` subclass and disabled the default `keyCommmands` by returning nil:

```
class KeyCommandDisabledTableView: UITableView {
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I then updated my `UITableViewController` subclass to use the new `KeyCommandDisabledTableView` subclass:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = KeyCommandDisabledTableView(
            frame: .zero, 
            style: .plain // or .grouped
        )
    }
}
```

Et voilà! The default arrow key handling is gone and my app's custom arrow key handling is now being called.

Comment: I tried using this since my `resignFirstResponder` solution stopped working in macOS 11.5. First, I had to add `canBecomeFirstResponder=true` in the `UITableView` subclass, or its `keyCommands` wouldn't be called. But even when doing that, the default key commands are still running. I confirmed that `tableView.keyCommands` had the up/down arrow commands before, and is now nil, so I don't know where the default commands are coming from. Does this solution still work for you?

Comment: @arlomedia Please see my updated answer and let me know if this is working for you. I have tested it in a sample project on macOS 11.6, macOS 12, and iOS 15.

Comment: Thanks for the update! This worked for me, but the first row in the table still became highlighted sometimes. I just posted a simpler solution that I got from an Apple DTS ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I further noticed that the default arrow key navigation only begins after clicking a row in a table, so I guessed the table must be assuming the first responder role. I added this to my table's delegate class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    #if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
    [tableView performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    #endif
}
```

That fixed it! Now the default keyboard navigation turns off as soon as it turns on, and doesn't interfere with my app's custom keyboard navigation.

(It didn't work without the delay.)

Comment: This solution stopped working for me in macOS 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 14 / macOS 11 makes it much easier to disable this behavior thanks to UITableView and UICollectionView's [selectionFollowsFocus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3573921-selectionfollowsfocus?language=objc) property:

```
tableView.selectionFollowsFocus = false
```

Comment: Sadly this is having no effect for me. (I tried calling it before and after the table is loaded/displayed.)